# Where is the do_CONNECT method in goagent being called?

Tags: python, http, proxy

I am reading an early version of goagent, I don't know where is the do_CONNECT method being called.

```
class GaeProxyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    ...
    def do_CONNECT(self):
        ...
```

The same method in the following page does not being called, either.
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935442/python-proxy-isnt-handling-post-requests)

Yes, if you search "do_CONNECT", you will get almost nothing, but to search "http method CONNECT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GaeProxyHandler's base class is BaseHTTPRequestHandler, so the code may be written in BaseHTTPRequestHandler

If you want to run the proxy, you should run the following code:

```
server = LocalProxyServer((common.LISTEN_IP, common.LISTEN_PORT), GAEProxyHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

So you know the server itself may write code about calling the method do_CONNECT now.

And let's see the backtrace, it actually does.

```
  File "E:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 616, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "E:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 639, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 596, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 610, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "E:\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 345, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "E:\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 666, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "E:\Python33\lib\http\server.py", line 400, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "E:\Python33\lib\http\server.py", line 388, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "E:\eclipse\workspace\GoAgent\src\goagent-local\proxy.py", line 1758, in **do_CONNECT**
```

see the last **do_CONNECT**?

Comment: I asked this question before I know CONNECT is just a method like GET or POST, one of the 7 http methods.

Answer (score 1):

CONNECT is a method like GET or POST, for the client to tell the PROXY server they need to finish the ssl handshake before sending request to the REAL server.

Thus, do_CONNECT would be called when there is an https request need to be forward.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697943/when-should-one-use-connect-and-get-http-methods-at-http-proxy-server)